# compare with previous number percentage algorithm flaw

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have 8 items in an array, I want to calculate the difference btw them. But my code has flaw, the output is wrong with different set of array.

What's wrong here?

```
const calculate_different_in_percentage = (num1, num2) => {

  //zero handling
  if (num2 === 0 && num1 > num2) {
    return 100
  }

  if (num1 === 0 && num1 < num2) {
    return 100
  }

  let result = 0
  if (num1 > num2) {
    result = ((num1 - num2) / num1) * 100
  } else if (num2 > num1) {
    result = ((num2 - num1) / num2) * 100
  } else {
    result = 0
  }

  if (!Number.isFinite(result)) result = 0

  return result.toFixed(1)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ptfqgcw/2/

from 362 to 1916 the difference should be 529% but it didn't happens in my case, couldn't spot what's wrong.

Comment: Please explain your logic and calculations *I want to calculate the difference btw them*.

Comment: 1916 is 529% of 362. 1916 is also 429% larger than 362.  You calculate the latter but you seem to want the former.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Show pls input data example and excpeted output

Answer (score 0):

> from 362 to 1916 the difference should be 529% but it didn't happens
>   in my case, couldn't spot what's wrong.

You are calculating the **percentage of difference between two elements in the order of appearance** rather than just the percentage as you mentioned in your question.

To simply get the percentage use this simple code

```
const calculate_different_in_percentage = (num1, num2) =>    (num2 != 0 && num1 != 0) ? ((num2/num1)*100).toFixed(1) : 0;
```

**Explanation**

- If num1 and num2 are not same and both numbers are not 0, then return `((num2/num1)*100).toFixed(1)`
- Else, return `0`

**Demo**

```js
let arr = [{ "total_count": 40}, {  "total_count": 20},{"total_count": 0}, {"total_count": 100}, {"total_count": 362}, {"total_count": 1916}, {"total_count": 4046}, {"total_count": 2473}];

const calculate_different_in_percentage = (num1, num2) => (num2 != 0 && num1 != 0) ? ((num2 / num1) * 100).toFixed(1) : 0;

const result = [];

arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
  if (!i) return
  result.push({
    count: obj.total_count,
    difference: calculate_different_in_percentage(arr[i - 1].total_count, obj.total_count)
  })
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if num2 is larger than num1? also from 0 to 40, the percentage is 100%, your logic missed that part.

Comment: Please share expected output for your input.